# How to compare the magnitude of a response among two groups?

Tags: group-differences, glmm, method-comparison

I performed generalized linear mixed models to test the effects of a treatment on two different groups (I performed a model for each group). Now I would like to test which of the groups is most affected by the treatment, that is to compare the magnitude of the response. I know how to test for difference in means, but now how to test for a difference in a magnitude. Could someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using group as a predictor in your model? If so, the coefficient tells you the difference in magnitude. You could bootstrap CIs for the coefficient to get your answer. A little bit more information on what/how you are doing the analysis would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thnink your answer give me some hint about what I should do. I performed two separate models, one for each group and got a coefficient for each group. But I thinl I should put both groups within the same model, using a dummy variable and test for a significant interactions among this doomy variable and my treatment. I am not proficient with bootsrtapping. Would you have an example?

Comment: It would be helpful if you described how you are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is 9 years old but it just popped up in my stream.

Don't do a separate model for each group. Combine the groups and use group as a covariate.